# "To whom it may concern" or "To whomever it may concern"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, whom, whoever-vs-whomever

Which is the best usage? "To whom it may concern" or "To whomever it may concern"?

Answer (score 2):

"To whom it may concern" is the bog-standard version. "Best" is in the eye of the beholder. Brevity is the soul of wit (and 'whom' is the shorter form).

Comment: Though I agree with "brevity is the soul of wit" in general, I don't see much chance for wit here.